# circuitikz 0.8.3 nigfete; undefined controle sequence

Tags: circuitikz

I'm using circuitikz to draw a circuit with an NMOSFET and like to use the nigfete node defined in circuitikz. When I try to compile my code I'm getting multiple undefined conrol sequence and Missing number errors. Since I'm allready using the newest ciruitikz version (0.8.3) and in all related problemsI could find updating the package fixed the problem I started this question.

Here are the first 5 errors:

> ! Undefined control sequence.\pgf@sh@bg@nigfete ...gftransformationadjustments\pgfsetcolor {\pgfkeysvalu... \draw (0,0) node [nigfete] {};
>
> ! Undefined control sequence.\drawfetcore #1-> \pgftransformationadjustments\pgfpathmoveto {\pgfpoint {... \draw (0,0) node [nigfete] {};
>
> ! Undefined control sequence. ...pgfverticaltransformationadjustment.5\pgflinewidth \draw (0,0) node [nigfete] {};
>
> ! Missing number, treated as zero.p \draw (0,0) node [nigfete] {};
>
> ! Undefined control sequence. ...fhorizontaltransformationadjustment.5\pgflinewidth \draw (0,0) node [nigfete] {};

The **MWE** I created this errors with is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
    \draw (0,0) node [nigfete] {};
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

However if I replace "nigfete" in the MWE with "op amp" or "gm amp" it compiles just fine.

For compiling I use the "latex + dvips + ps2pdf + view pdf" chain of TexMaker.

Last but not least here is the line with the circuitikz version from the log file:

> Package: circuitikz 2017/05/28{} The CircuiTikz circuit drawing package version
> 0.8.3

Thanks to everyone who helps me!

Comment: Please update your pgf/tikz version.

Comment: I do not get any error with your example. Neither using `pdflatex` nor `latex`. I've tested with `pgf` 3.0.0 and `circuitikz` 0.3.0, 0.4, 0.8.1 and 0.8.3.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem is outdated and can be solved by updating a package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updating pgf/tikz to a version > 3 did the trick. (Forgot to look into the requirements of circuitikz after I had updated it.)

Thanks to sistlind.